# How to List to JQuery Function using Java code?

Tags: java, jquery, jsf

I Have to pass my **List to JQuery Function using java code** and we are using **JSF** as Framework So how to pass list???

Can any one tell me ... and Thanks in advance......

Comment: Just generate a script tag with the necessary JavaScript code in your JSF.

Answer (score 0):

by just type that

```
#{yourBeanName.yourListVariableName}
```

write this code to where you wan't to pass the list..